# Firefox add-on for offline to-do list

Tags: firefox, offline, productivity

I need a Firefox extension for **offline** to-do list management that is able to:

- add tabs (title & URL) to list
- add content of page (links, images) to list
- export list as a universal format that is parse-able (XML, JSON,
  CSV, …)

Is there such an add-on?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/). It allows you to store full pages for offline reading, manage and export them. It does not really support exporting just the metadata, but the internal file which stores the list (scrapbook.rdf) is xml. Besides that each item is stored/exported in it's own folder. That folder contains a index.dat textfile which contains multiple rows in the format "".